# Why placeholder text is not showing of textInput field in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make a text input field where placeholder text will show "Enter your digit" in react-native, Now problem is, the placeholder text is not showing until i am pressing any key in the keyboard. If i elaborate then when i am running the app placeholder text is empty, if i click on text input field then keyboard appears. Now if i press any digit then it shows those digit perfectly and if i press cross button and delete all digit which i entered only that time that placeholder text shows. I am new in react-native so if someone know about the problem then please explain before answer because so far i have not got any detail about this matter. So far what i have done.

`<TextInput style={styles.textField} placeholder="Enter your digit" placeholderTextColor= 'red' keyboardType= 'numeric'> </TextInput>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's because the textinput has some value in his value property, can you try to use `value=''` ?

```
 <TextInput 
  style={styles.textField} 
  placeholder="Enter your digit" 
  placeholderTextColor= 'red' 
  value=''
  keyboardType= 'numeric' />
```

If that works try using some state value like this.state.text, and make the initial value null or ''  (empty string)

Comment: Thanks you are right...Text input field was taking empty string. :)

Comment: Oh, okay. Now it's working. The problem was not the value attribute, it's because the tag was not self-closing.

Comment: ```<TextInput style={styles.textField} placeholder="Enter your digit" placeholderTextColor= 'red' keyboardType= 'numeric' />``` this also giving me my desire result.

Comment: Oh then it was the tag , maybe the space between `<TextInput> </TextInput>` was taken as the initial value C:

Answer (score 3):

Your TextInput tag should be self-closing.

Comment: yeah its worked what is the difference between both